# why doesn't jquery see changes in page after .load()?

Tags: jquery

I just tried changing my page contents with jQuery's .load methdod.

While the contents changed without problem, I found that jQuery was still "seeing" the old content if I tried to select something, an example:

page:

```
 <div id="mycontentarea">
   <div id="myfirstcontent"></div>
   <div id="mysecondcontent"></div>
</div>
```

replacing content:

```
<div id=mythirdcontent"></div>
<div id=myfourthcontent"></div>
```

javascript:

```
// replace original content
$('#mycontentarea').load('replacement.html');
// print out the id of the first child
console.log($("#mycontentarea").children().attr("id"));
```

The console will print out "myfirstcontent" instead of "mythirdcontent" - why?

Comment: you need to use jQueries `live` or `delegate` if you are using `load` to dynamically reattach events to dynamic content instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is asynchronous and your `console.log` call is executed before the replacement happens.

Move any code that relies on the result of the call to `load` to a callback which is executed upon successful completion:

```
$('#mycontentarea').load('replacement.html', function() {
    //Anything in here is executed once the content has been returned successfully
    console.log($("#mycontentarea").children().attr("id"));
});
```

From the docs on `load`:

> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after
>   post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is
>   fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set
>   to each DOM element in turn.